# Reading a XML file input in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, file-handling

We have few load runner scripts that take XML file as input and reads these xml files for data.

For example:

while (!feof(file_ptr))

```
{
      /* Check for file I/O errors */
      if (ferror(file_ptr)) 
                              {
           lr_output_message("Error reading file %s", filename);
           break;
      }
```

}

Please let me know if we can handle these file handling operations (other than CSV file) in jmeter

Answer (score 1):

You can use [__FileToString](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) function to read an arbitrary file into a JMeter Variable which can later be used anywhere in the current thread group.

Refer to [How to Use JMeter Functions](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) post series for extra information on this and other various helpful JMeter functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BeanShell Sampler for reading the XML file.

You can write a code in BeanShell sampler to read the xml file which you can write in JAVA.

And you can store the xml contents in Object type you want i.e Hashtable, ArrayList etc...